# Anyone know why the hyperlink wont work

Tags: hyperlink

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\title{May 2018 Summary}
\author{MM}
\date{June 1, 2018}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Tasks and Deliverables}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Hello World

\end{enumerate}

\textbf(Note} All the files shared have been included on
\hyperlink{google.ca}{OneDrive}


\end{document}
```

I am viewing the PDF using PDFLaTeX

Comment: What's a protocol? I used this site: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Hyperlinks for help

Comment: Even that page does state you're on the wrong track, because they mention other means of linking to websites than `\hyperlink` which isn't intended for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something completely different: As hyperlink is primarily useful for linking within the document you want to use `\href` which takes two arguments.

For that to work you also need to fix your `\textbf(Note}` to use another curly brace at the beginning.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\title{May 2018 Summary}
\author{MM}
\date{June 1, 2018}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Tasks and Deliverables}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Hello World

\end{enumerate}

\textbf{Note} All the files shared have been included on
\href{https://google.ca}{OneDrive}


\end{document}
```